# How to access "python3.6/site-packages" directory?

Tags: python, directory, numpy

So right now I am trying to import tflearn on a python script, but that returns the error

```
AttributeError: type object 'numpy.ndarray' has no attribute '__array_function__'
```

(Theres a huge error statement, but this is the last line)

A person on Stack Overflow got the same error, and people are recommending to him to reinstall numpy completely. I thought with `pip uninstall numpy`/`pip3 uninstall numpy` it is done, but when importing numpy it is still there.

So a person on Stack Overflow made this specific answer:

> remove the whole numpy directory and numpy disc info in the
>   python3.6/site-packages and type pip3 install numpy

So I would like to try that. How do I access the python3.6 directory? Since I dont know in which folders it is, I dont know where to change my directory to.

I am not using Anaconda by the way, this is the standalone Python 3 installation.

Answer (score 0):

For people who want to know the path to a script file that throws an error, the path is shown in the error log right in the console.